# Gitlab: Cloning (via ssh) on a fresh install fails with "The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: gitlab

## The problem

Gitlab 5.3stable

I have made a fresh install on my Debian 7.0 server. Everything seems to work fine, except that when I'm about to clone an existing project:

```
$ git clone gitlab:root/fastalook.git
Cloning into 'fastalook'...
Debian GNU/Linux 7
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Even though ssh:ing works without a problem:

```
$ ssh gitlab
Debian GNU/Linux 7
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!
Connection to gitlab.rzetterberg.se closed.
```

Cloning/push via http works fine:

```
$ git clone http://gitlab.rzetterberg.se:666/root/fastalook.git
Cloning into 'fastalook'...
Username for 'http://gitlab.rzetterberg.se:666': root          
Password for 'http://root@gitlab.rzetterberg.se:666':
remote: Counting objects: 1589, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (621/621), done.
remote: Total 1589 (delta 884), reused 1589 (delta 884)
Receiving objects: 100% (1589/1589), 1.65 MiB | 1.39 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (884/884), done.
```

## Configuration

### Ssh config

```
Host gitlab
    Hostname gitlab.rzetterberg.se
    Port 22000
    User git
```

### Check output

```
$ bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.8, but has dynamically loaded 2.8.0
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.4.0 ? ... OK (1.4.0)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
post-receive hook up-to-date? ... yes
post-receive hooks in repos are links: ... 
Richard Zetterberg / Fastalook ... ok

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.8, but has dynamically loaded 2.8.0
yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... yes
Projects have satellites? ... 
Richard Zetterberg / Fastalook ... yes
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.7.10)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

### Env:info output

```
git@paralyzed:~/gitlab$ bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.8, but has dynamically loaded 2.8.0

System information
System:         Debian 7.1
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   1.9.3p392
Gem Version:    1.8.23
Bundler Version:1.3.5
Rake Version:   10.0.4

GitLab information
Version:        5.3.0
Revision:       0c39f4d
Directory:      /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter:     mysql2
URL:            http://gitlab.rzetterberg.se:666
HTTP Clone URL: http://gitlab.rzetterberg.se:666/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@gitlab.rzetterberg.se:some-project.git
Using LDAP:     no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:        1.4.0
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:          /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:            /usr/bin/git
```

### Gitlab config

```
production: &base
  gitlab:
    host: gitlab.rzetterberg.se
    port: 666
    https: false
    email_from: gitlab@gitlab.rzetterberg.se
    support_email: support@gitlab.rzetterberg.se
    default_projects_limit: 10
    default_projects_features:
      issues: true
      merge_requests: true
      wiki: true
      wall: false
      snippets: false

  gravatar:
    enabled: true                 # Use user avatar image from Gravatar.com (default: true)

  satellites:
    path: /home/git/gitlab-satellites/

  backup:
    path: "tmp/backups"   # Relative paths are relative to Rails.root (default: tmp/backups/)

  gitlab_shell:
    repos_path: /home/git/repositories/
    hooks_path: /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/

    upload_pack: true
    receive_pack: true

  git:
    bin_path: /usr/bin/git
    max_size: 5242880 # 5.megabytes
    timeout: 10

  extra:

development:
  <<: *base

test:
  <<: *base
  issues_tracker:
    redmine:
      project_url: "http://redmine/projects/:issues_tracker_id"
      issues_url: "http://redmine/:project_id/:issues_tracker_id/:id"
      new_issue_url: "http://redmine/projects/:issues_tracker_id/issues/new"

staging:
  <<: *base
```

**Edit: Add output of /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys and key in gitlab profile**

### Gitlab key in profile

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCwiQfkb9LpHP1yI1ffGfuXYMmRiW7nBmRW9q7keLphmjvxpMcwFLtANfMIxhXE6wxBpJewtJkP1Gdye8awYknm2Mk5c/Yal67KL4SL0RIT+XTrcT8Y6c+5MSOSd5R0o/3ohxRMXVO7Wg4PIB//uSaG9LZvduIaxONdV8y7Qs5kp7vFXZ6KS+5Qcksy4vqzivgTqdjtqU9b2fXBu8nd7SmYxdzKML8HUi7To5Y15Z0LzuJDxtgz6wHMLz3m4cOS9rb2zJZ3toii4wdJnYigHkoYxOnk0p6gPmbM0bxOEJKSpPp5BUUpwbLL+SJYlyn8FaaSeEzfmKbsH0ucoboPOgXD zed@shinigami
```

### Authorized keys

```
command="/home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell key-1",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCwiQfkb9LpHP1yI1ffGfuXYMmRiW7nBmRW9q7keLphmjvxpMcwFLtANfMIxhXE6wxBpJewtJkP1Gdye8awYknm2Mk5c/Yal67KL4SL0RIT+XTrcT8Y6c+5MSOSd5R0o/3ohxRMXVO7Wg4PIB//uSaG9LZvduIaxONdV8y7Qs5kp7vFXZ6KS+5Qcksy4vqzivgTqdjtqU9b2fXBu8nd7SmYxdzKML8HUi7To5Y15Z0LzuJDxtgz6wHMLz3m4cOS9rb2zJZ3toii4wdJnYigHkoYxOnk0p6gPmbM0bxOEJKSpPp5BUUpwbLL+SJYlyn8FaaSeEzfmKbsH0ucoboPOgXD zed@shinigami
```

Comment: Why are you cloning an https repo as 'root'? And are you using the root account when cloning with ssh url?

Comment: My gitlab user is named `root`. My ssh url: `gitlab:root/fastalook.git`.

Comment: No I am not talking about the 'root' namespace created after a gitlab user

Comment: I am referring to the login 'root' you are using for https authentication. Why would you use the root account?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. When I'm using http am I not supposed to use the credentials for my gitlab user?

Comment: Ok, but do you have the right `~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` file under the home of the account you are in as a client? Ie the public key registered in the gitlab `root` account ssh keys page?

Comment: Yes, the keys match. Otherwise `ssh gitlab` would fail, if I'm not mistaken. See my edit for output of pub keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading gitlab-shell from v1.4.0 to v1.5.0 solves this problem. Which means there must be some sort of bug and not a configuration issue.

I have reported this at gitlabs issue tracker, see https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4599